# The time at which the tank would be full given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A rectangular tank has dimensions 5 m x 3 m x 2 m. There are three inlet pipes P. Q. R, which have filling rates of 2 m3 / hr. 3 m3 / hr and 5 m3 / hr respectively. At 9:00 am. when the tank was empty,P was opened. Q was opened at 9 30 a.m. and R was opened at 10:30 am. The time at which the tank would be full is

MyApproach:

I here can get the volume of the tank as ($5$ . $3$ . $2$) m^3= $30$ m^3

Now if p is alone opened for 30 minute i.e half an hour ,till $9$.$30$  $1$

m^3 will be filled up.Then P+Q is filling it for next $1$ hr so now at

$10$.$30$ ?

I am unable to calculate here

Am I right in my approach.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Between 9:30 and 10:30 what is the total inflow? What is the total inflow after 10:30, for how much left to fill?

Answer (score 0):

First calculate volume of water being pumped to the tank until 9.30a.m. If the tank is not fully filled then calculate the volume being pumped to the tank.If the tank is not fully filed then calculate the empty volume of the tank and divide it from the sum of the filling rates.So you would be able to calculate the time easily..

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The volume of the tank is $30 \; m^3$.

At $9.30$ it contains $30 \; m^3$.  At $9.30$ the inflow becomes $2+3=5\; m^3/h$, so, after one hour, at $10.30$ the tank contains $6\; m^3$. Now the flux becomes $5+5=10\; m^3/h$, so your problem is represented by the simple equation:

$$
6+10 t=30
$$
where $t$ is time, in hours starting from $10.30$. Can you solve this?